# Updated nested Object in ReactJS functional component

Tags: reactjs

I have a series of nested objects stored in state, I am trying to update the email / sms data fields.  This working quite well.

The question I have is this, is there a better way in which to code the "onChange" handler?

Nested object

```
  const [settings, setSettings] = useState({
    notifications: {
      contact: {
        email: true,
        sms: false
      },
      updates: {
        email: true,
        sms: true
      }
    }
  });
```

Checkbox onChange handler function

```
  const onCheckBoxChanged = (e, settingType, settingSubType, checked) => {
    setSettings(prevState => {
      const updated = { ...prevState };
      updated.notifications[settingType][settingSubType] = checked;
      return updated;
    });
  };
```

The checkbox is part of semantic-ui-react.

```
<Checkbox checked={settings.notifications.contact.email} 
  onChange={(e, { checked }) => onCheckBoxChanged(e, "contact", "email", checked)} />
```

A working example can be found here [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-roentgen-td19v?file=/src/App.js)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have done cuple of small optimisations.

See [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-sun-ukkqr?file=/src/App.js)

The alternative method to updating your state would be:

[Updating Multidimensional Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51830338/updating-value-of-multidimensional-array-of-object)

I think using a temp variable for this usecase is acceptable.